# Integrating a subselect in a select in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, subquery

I have a need to take a date from a table and calculate a new date which is a increment of business days.  At the moment the code does not consider holidays, just Saturday and Sunday.

I am new to Oracle and still am struggling with how it works.  I need some help.

I have a script which performs the date calculation.  In my example it simply calculates a date 15 days from the current date.  Here is the code:

```
SELECT sysdate,
(SELECT dt from
(SELECT dt, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dt) pos
    FROM (SELECT TRUNC(sysdate) + LEVEL dt,
            CASE
                WHEN TRIM (TO_CHAR (sysdate + LEVEL, 'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY'
                  or TRIM (TO_CHAR (sysdate + LEVEL, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
                  THEN 0
                  ELSE 1
                END cnt
            FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 30)
        WHERE cnt = 1)
    WHERE pos = 15) as myDate
FROM DUAL;
```

The result is current date and a date 15 business days in the future.

Then I tried to include this in a SELECT with my table.  The objective is to take the date from each record in the table and perform the calculation.  Here is the code:

```
SELECT assgn_id, assgn_date,
(SELECT dt from
(SELECT dt, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dt) pos
    FROM (SELECT TRUNC(assgn_date) + LEVEL dt,
            CASE
                WHEN TRIM (TO_CHAR (assgn_date + LEVEL, 'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY'
                  or TRIM (TO_CHAR (assgn_date + LEVEL, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
                  THEN 0
                  ELSE 1
                END cnt
            FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 30)
        WHERE cnt = 1)
    WHERE pos = 15) as due_date
FROM sales_assgn;
```

What I got from this was a list with all the entries in the sales_assgn table.  The first result line had a good due_date calculated.  However, every other entry on the output had the same due_date as the first line.  So obviously the sub-query is not executing with every record.

What do I need to do to to make this work properly.

Comment: I doubt your query even works. Because assgn_date won't be available for the inner query. Are you sure you pasted the right query here?

Comment: I'm surprised it ran at all, since you're accessing `assgn_date` so many nested levels deep.  Which version of Oracle are you on?

Comment: I am using 11g.

It definitely works as described.  I would like to be able to do this with a function but we're not allowed to add functions.  I tried changing the DUAL in the inner level to the sales_assgn table with a where that links the outer level id to the inner level.  But it just sits there and spins.

Comment: I know this is terribly inefficient.  At the moment it is a one time effort to implement some new functionality.  The sql is being run to initialize the due dates.  In the future it will be maintained through the application.  I am required to perform the load of the due dates from SQL and not develop a load using Java.  So this entire exercise is not my choice.  It is an opportunity to learn about Oracle.  That's the only upside.

Comment: If your query really works, then try this. You're missing "partition by", (SELECT dt, RANK() OVER (partition by assgn_date ORDER BY dt) pos
    FROM (SELECT assgn_date, TRUNC(assgn_date) + LEVEL dt,

Comment: LOL  I said it is running.  It absolutely isn't running correctly!!!  Much of the Oracle is soooo different from MySQL where I've got most of my SQL experience.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: OK.  I added the partition as suggested.  It didn't change the result.  Evidently it's not going back and running the sub-selects with each record read from clm_usr_assgn.

Comment: What is clm_usr_assgn? I don't see that in the query above?

Comment: I'm sorry.  It's sales_assgn.  I'm working on 2 different issues.  This is the table that shows what sales people are assigned to which contracts.  We have a new due date on that table that shows when they have to update their contract records.

Answer (score 1):

If the only interval you care about is 15 days exclusive of Holidays, then on a five day work week this is always going to be a 21 calendar day gap unless you start on a Saturday (20 calendar day gap to the Friday) or a Sunday (19 calendar days to the Friday). So generating a list of days and counting through them is an unnecessary performance hit and could be done simply like this:

```
select assign_date + CASE when TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date , 'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY' then 20
                      when TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date , 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY' then 19
                      else 21 end
from yourtable;
```

That being said, if you want to count the days with an eye towards future flexibility in day counts or joining to a table of holidays then this works. It does a running sum of your cnt counter, and note that I moved the generator of 30 integers into a seperate query from dual and then cross joined it to the source so that the 30-count is applied against each source row.:

```
with dat as (
   select sysdate assign_date from dual union all
   select sysdate+1 assign_date from dual union all
   select sysdate+2 assign_date from dual union all
   select sysdate+3 assign_date from dual )
select assign_date
      , min(future_date) as future_Date
from (        
select assign_date
       ,trunc(assign_date) + lvl future_Date
       ,sum(CASE
            WHEN TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date + lvl, 'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY'
              or TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date + lvl, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END ) over (partition by assign_date order by lvl) gap 
from dat
cross join  (select level lvl from dual connect by level < 30) seq
)
where gap = 15
group by assign_Date
```

The MIN() and group by is required because for a Friday there will be a future Friday, Saturday, and Sunday calendar days that are all 15 work days in the future. If you want to replace that with a RANK() or FIRST_VALUE() it would also work.

If you want a better look at how it is figuring it out, I've added a couple of columns to the inner query portion here to help you get a handle on it.

```
with dat as (
   select sysdate assign_date from dual union all
   select sysdate+1 assign_date from dual union all
   select sysdate+2 assign_date from dual union all
   select sysdate+3 assign_date from dual )
select assign_date
       ,trunc(assign_date) + lvl future_Date
       ,lvl
       ,CASE
            WHEN TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date + lvl, 'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY'
              or TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date + lvl, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END cnt
       ,sum(CASE
            WHEN TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date + lvl, 'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY'
              or TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date + lvl, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END ) over (partition by assign_date order by lvl) gap 
from dat
cross join  (select level lvl from dual connect by level < 30) seq
order by assign_Date, lvl
```

Which actually steered me towards an easier way of condensing down to the correct future day without needing a MIN() or RANK in the outer query because it will always be the row where gap=15 and the cnt=1, and repeating the same CASE statement in the inner query is more efficient. Proving, once again, that there are almost always multiple solutions.

```
with dat as (
   select sysdate assign_date from dual union all
   select sysdate+1 assign_date from dual union all
   select sysdate+2 assign_date from dual union all
   select sysdate+3 assign_date from dual )
SELECT assign_date
     , future_date
FROM (   
    select assign_date
           ,trunc(assign_date) + lvl future_Date
           ,lvl
           ,CASE
                WHEN TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date + lvl, 'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY'
                  or TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date + lvl, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END cnt
           ,sum(CASE
                WHEN TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date + lvl, 'DAY')) = 'SATURDAY'
                  or TRIM (TO_CHAR (assign_date + lvl, 'DAY')) = 'SUNDAY'
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END ) over (partition by assign_date order by lvl) gap 
    from dat
    cross join  (select level lvl from dual connect by level < 30) seq
    order by assign_Date, lvl 
)
where gap = 15 
and cnt = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you.  it will take me a while to examine it and make sure I understand what it is doing.  I appreciate everyone's comments and assistance.

Comment: Added another query of just the internal bits with some aditional columns to help you see how it works. Cheers,

Comment: It is amazing how different perspectives can generate totally different results!!  Your suggestion of just using a standard 21 day increment unless the start date is on  the weekend is fantastic.  At this point there has been nothing said about taking holidays into account.  So I'm not.  I'll be using your first solution.  If the holiday issue comes up then I'll use your second solution.  I really appreciate the help.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

It could be a bug in Oracle, I can't find any other explanation.
It seems that Oracle "optimised" the subquery and returns the same result for all records.
Try this query, it works on Oracle 12c (I haven't tested it on 11.2)

```
SELECT assgn_id, assgn_date,
      ( 
         SELECT dt from  (
            SELECT dt, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dt) pos
                , s.assgn_date
            FROM (
                SELECT TRUNC(s.assgn_date) + LEVEL dt,
                       CASE WHEN TRIM (TO_CHAR (s.assgn_date + LEVEL, 'DAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')) 
                                 IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
                            THEN 0 ELSE 1
                      END cnt
                FROM DUAL
                CONNECT BY LEVEL < 30
            )
            WHERE cnt = 1
          )
          WHERE pos = 15
      ) as due_date
FROM sales_assgn s;
```

The essential change is here, I've added `assgn_date` to the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT dt, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dt) pos
                    , s.assgn_date
```

I've also added NLS settings to the CASE expression, because your query doesn't work if NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE setting is other than English or American.

```
CASE WHEN TRIM (TO_CHAR (s.assgn_date + LEVEL, 'DAY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')) 
          IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
     THEN 0 ELSE 1
     END cnt
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.  The only thing I can come up with is that the signature of the select didn't include anything from the source table.  By adding the assgn_dte to the 2nd level sub-query Oracle chose not to optimize it.  Thank you.  I now have 2 solutions that work.  Actually this solution works a lot faster than I would have thought.  Thank you very, very much!!!